# how can i show doc or rtf or pdf in flash player or in none editble format

Tags: flash, pdf, rtf

i need to show in my web application document that is in pdf or rtf format in 
some kind of none edible format that can't be changed and cant be downloaded 
the perfect candidate is the flash player , but i know the tool that converting pdf or rdf to 
swf is not free. im looking for free solutions , does not have to be flash .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [pdf2swf](http://www.swftools.org/) and in general the SWF tools.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [Flashpaper](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashpaper/), which can convert every format to non-editible flash. It installs a printer, so to convert say a Word document, you just have to go to Word and print the document with the Flash Paper printer. It prints a non-editible swf file.

Comment: Flashpaper does not seem to be a free app.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use the [Page Turning Software](http://www.pageturnpro.com/) for the Printing your publication in [Digital Publication](http://www.pageturnpro.com/) which is non editable.

Answer (score 0):

U can also use flexpaper together with pdf2swf, its a open source viewer http://www.devaldi.com/?p=350